# Closing a pdf by reading the file size

Tags: excel, vba

I am auto creating pdf's from a list of items in excel.  Everything is working fine but sometimes the created pdf is corrupted since the program closes the original too fast.  I realize I could add time to the `Application.Wait` but sometimes that will add a lot of time if the list is very long.  I am trying to read the file size using `FileLen` and looping until that value is greater than 0 and then close the file.  My code below is throwing an error saying **Next without For**.

Any help is appreciated.

```
For WaitTime = 0 To 0.5
If FileLen(SavePDFFldr & "\" & Description & ".pdf") > 10 Then
    Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True
    Application.SendKeys "{numlock}%s", True                    ' Closes the template when the file is done saving
    Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
Else: Next WaitTime
```

Where the SavePDFFldr and Description are set prior to this.

Comment: Excel has an PDF export function. This function will create the PDF file and after that the next line in your code will run.

Comment: I do know that however I can't utilize it since I am inputting data from excel into a template pdf and then printing that pdf as a new one.  So technically I am working through that pdf software (Foxit PhantomPDF)

Comment: So, you use `Sendkeys` to control Foxit PhantomPDF, right?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok, then you could add a kind of infinite loop to wait

Comment: Yup, thats kinda what I'm asking here in this question.  I'm trying to loop that wait until it reads a file size.  But my current code is running into an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments you could add a "infinite" loop

```
    Do While FileLen(SavePDFFldr & "\" & Description & ".pdf") < 10
        ' Dangerous this could end up in a endless loop
        ' we just loop and give other applications time
        ' to do something
        DoEvents
    Loop

 ' Hopefully you get here 
        Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True
        Application.SendKeys "{numlock}%s", True                    ' Closes the template when the file is done saving
        Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
        Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and get back to you.

Comment: I've started getting stuck in the infinite loop.  Is there a way to stop that loop function after a certain amount of time

Comment: As I wrote this can happen. On the other hand it means that  `FileLen < 10 ` is true all the time which seems strange resp your PDF file is just not bigger. I added a second answer to provide an example to leave such kind of loop based on a second condition. But then the code which will run after the loop might not run in the way you would like it to run.

Answer (score 0):

The question raised in the comment could be answered like that. You add a second exit condition to the loop which leaves the loop after a couple of seconds.

```
Sub LoopTest()

Dim a As Long
Dim startTime As Date
Dim endTime As Date
    startTime = Now
    endTime = startTime + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Do While a < 10
        ' Without a second condition this is an endless loop

        ' this example will leave the loop after ~3 seconds
        If Now > endTime Then
            MsgBox "Done"
            Exit Do
        End If

        'DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```